# How to use an external library in my component?

Tags: components, lazarus, indy10, idhttp

I created a component , and I need to use IdHttp component (Indy) in it, so first I installed Indy in my IDE,I created the component and istalled it, then I added to uses the unit IdHttp so I can use IdHttp in my component.
But, when I compile the code of my component I get this error: Can't find unit IdHttp used by "mycomponent".PS: I added indylaz to the required packages of my component , however when I recompile the component I get the same compilation error.
So how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to write IdHTTP instead of IdHttp, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Add a requirement of the project on the package that contains your component. That will the recursively load your component's requirementss.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't fix the error.